# Windows Mobile and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, mobile-phone

I currently run Ubuntu 9.10 at home. My wife just bought a Samsung Omnia with Windows ME on it. Is there a way that I can get it to talk to my PC? It came with CD's but the CD's only run under Windows. I have not yet tried WINE, but I am afraid to. WINE has been so hit and miss, that I dread even trying. Any ideas?

Comment: Phone running Windows ME? Oh you mean Windows Mobile!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a program called [SynCE](http://www.synce.org/moin/) to allow communication with Windows Mobile, and according to the download and installation page it suggests there are stable versions for most versions of Linux.  Hopefully it should be able to achieve what you are after.

While looking I did see a program called [Multisync](http://multisync.sourceforge.net/news.php), but it looks like it was abandoned in favour of [Opensync](http://www.opensync.org/) which appears to have lost the support for Windows CE.

Windows Mobile is based on Windows CE, hence the SynCE name...

Curious to see how you get on, I'd be tempted to try Activesync on WINE, but doubt it would work as you'd need full USB support in order to communicate with your phone.  Perhaps running Windows XP in VirtualBox to get USB access?  Not the best solution I admit but given how virtual machine USB support is surprisingly good I suspect it is the most likely to work ...

Comment: SyncCE is the way to go. It comes with a tray utility for Gnome and KDE as well. I run Gentoo, and had to enable RNDIS related options in my kernel config, but you will probably have it on by default. There was a bug where I had to apply a small patch to my kernel before I compiled it each time to work with WinMo 6.x, but maybe that is all fixed now. With Gnome it should integrate right in and work with Evolution (if you use that). I had an HTC Titan, and dumped it for a Palm device which works with no trouble w/ KDE4 and it's data back-end. Expect to file browse, be happy if you get more.

Comment: I have tried this from the SyncCE website, but all I got was error messages when trying to install. It seems like they may not support 9.10 yet? any clues?

Comment: Sorry, can't really help much. I use Gentoo, and if it compiles and all dependencies are met it will (usually) work. You can try doing it all from source as far as the SynCE packages go and see about deps. from your package manager to make it easier.

Comment: Did you go through your package manager and install SynCE or did you download it?  Problem is with Linux being so configurable you never know if that one last piece of support the package needs from your kernel has been enabled.  Check the package manager that comes with Ubuntu, hopefully it should be able to install dependancies...

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this again, from the source... and whaddya know... it works! Now I can access the storage on the phone and computer. Thanks for everyone!